# JQuery Modal dialog close event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a ruby-on-rails application, which shows a modal dialog form for first-time users. However, if users close the dialog, I want to redirect the user to home page. How do I do that? Here's my JQuery snippet. Thanks.

```
this.dialog(
    {
        modal:true, 
        width:'auto',
        height:'auto',
        title: 'New to Purchest? Subscribe to deals that interest you!'

        close: function(event, ui) {  }
    }
)
```

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery

Comment: To clarify, you're using the jQuery UI Dialog library here, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's as simple as adding code to that `close` callback:

```
this.dialog(
{
    modal:true, 
    width:'auto',
    height:'auto',
    title: 'New to Purchest? Subscribe to deals that interest you!'

    close: function(event, ui) {
        top.location.href = 'http://www.wheredoyouwanttogotoday.com';
        // ^^ obscure microsoft marketing reference
    }
});
```